# How to exclude another logic and improve performance of unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to improve performance of unit tests in my project. If I write test in one logic I need to write another logic in my test. I reproduce it like this: 
I have class ProductInfo

```
    public class ProductInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And class Product:

```
 public class Product
{
    public ProductInfo Info { get; set; }

    private decimal price;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            Info.Title = $"{Info.Name}-{price} USD";
        }
    }
}
```

I create unit test for setting Price

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ProductInfoTitleTest()
    {
        decimal price = 120;
        string productName = "Product1";
        ProductInfo info = new ProductInfo() { Name = productName };
        Product product = new Product() { Info = info };
        product.Price = price;
        Assert.AreEqual($"{productName}-{price} USD", product.Info.Title, "Both should be equal");
    }
```

Created test pass. So, I create another properties in Product class :

```
public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Price * Quantity;
        }
    }
```

Then I create test for testing TotalPrice:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProductTotalPriceTest()
    {
        Product product = new Product
        {
            Price = 100,
            Quantity = 2
        };
        Assert.AreEqual(200, product.TotalPrice, "It should be 200");
    }
```

This test fails, because I didn't set product info. So, I do this:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void ProductTotalPriceTest()
    {
        Product product = new Product
        {
            Info = new ProductInfo(),
            Price = 100,
            Quantity = 2
        };
        Assert.AreEqual(200, product.TotalPrice, "It should be 200");
    }
```

Then test pass. Is there any way to do this without setting product info (without changing logic)?  I hope that I could understand use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to exclude another logic

**You should not**. Valid instance of `ProductInfo` is part of the "contract" of `Product` class.

I would even suggest make `ProductInfo` argument of the constructor, to explicitly show consumers of the class, that without it class will not work properly.

If configuration of class under the test become to complicated, create helper/builder classes/functions where logic for configuration will remain in same place.

For example:

```
public class ProductBuilder
{
    private string _productName;
    private decimal _price;
    private int _quantity;

    public ProductBuilder ProductName(string name)
    {
        _productName = name;
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder Price(decimal price)
    {
        _price = price;
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder Quantity(int quantity)
    {
        _quantity = quantity;
        return this;
    }

    public Product Create()
    {
        return new Product
        {
            Info = new ProductInfo { Name = _productName },
            Price = _price,
            Quantity = _price, 
        }
    }
}
```

Then in tests you will be able to create valid instance of type `Product`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void InfoTitel_ReturnsProductNameAndPrice()
{
    var builder = new ProductBuilder();

    var product = builder.ProductName("Device X").Price(100).Create();

    product.Info.Title.Should().Be("Device X-100.00 USD");
}

[TestMethod]
public void TotalPrice_CalculatesFromPriceAndQuantity()
{
    var builder = new ProductBuilder();

    var product = builder.Price(35.99m).Quantity(2).Create();

    product.TotalPrice.Should().Be(71.98m);
}
```

By encapsulating configuration into dedicated class you will be able to change configuration logic without touching every test. Unless, of course you will change public contract of the class.

Comment: I think, its not good idea to create ProductBuilder class. If I create this class, I need to create new method when I add new test. For example, As you show, you are creating method for each property of Product class. I think there should be another way (Patterns, packages .... ). Because in my case I'm testing TotalPrice and I don't need set ProductInfo to test. Setting Price  is tested in another test. If I set ProdutInfo in each test, It will be performance problem.

Comment: With implementation you have (Price setter) you are force to instantiate a ProductInfo for ane test where `Price` is involved. You don't need to add new method to the builder for every test, Builder will contain a logic to create a *valid* instance of Product.

Comment: What is difference between your answer and @User's answer. I can create valid instance of Product in [TestInitialize] and use it for each test, but performance  problem will not be solved!

Comment: Performance problem(if instantiating `ProductInfo` will cause such) not in the tests. It is in the `Product` class, where Price setter requires `ProductInfo` to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good opportunity to use a test initializer to instantiate the `Product` with a `ProductInfo` before each test, then just modify it as necessary.

```
[TestClass]
public class ProductTests
{
    Product product;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        product = new Product { Info = new ProductInfo() };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProductInfoTitleTest()
    {
        decimal price = 120;
        string productName = "Product1";
        product.Info.Name = productName;
        product.Price = price;
        Assert.AreEqual($"{productName}-{price} USD", product.Info.Title, "Both should be equal");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProductTotalPriceTest()
    {
        product.Price = 100;
        product.Quantity = 2;
        Assert.AreEqual(200, product.TotalPrice, "It should be 200");
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be performance problem, because in each test you are creating ProductInfo for product (even if I don't need ProductInfo in some tests)

Comment: I just reproduce my problem with Product and ProductInfo. As you said problem is:  **it's got a constructor that's doing a bunch of stuff**